# How to craft a dummy_input for a pytorch model to be exported into onnx format?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, onnx

I am trying to export [DiffDock](https://github.com/gcorso/DiffDock) in `.onnx` format. Since I was trying to craft the dummy_data reading all of the requirements of forward function. I ended up having data of type dict(Dictionary) but there were some other attributes like complex_t which were accessed through dot notation like data.complex_t which is not supported in dict. So I defined data as a custom class which can allow both dot notation and dictionary style access to data. But that custom class is not one of the expected types by export function. As they allow only tuples,lists and variables.(Dictionaries and strings are also accepted, but their usage is not recommended.)

I simply added following part to `inference.py` below the line no. `101 model.eval()`

```
num_ligand_nodes = 23
num_receptor_nodes = 416
num_atom_nodes = 100 
num_features = 1281  

dummy_data = {
    'ligand': {
        'x': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes, num_features)),
        'pos': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes, 3)),
        'edge_mask': torch.ones((num_ligand_nodes,)),
        'batch': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes,), dtype=torch.long),
        'ptr': torch.tensor([0, num_ligand_nodes], dtype=torch.long),
    },
    'receptor': {
        'x': torch.zeros((num_receptor_nodes, num_features)),
        'pos': torch.zeros((num_receptor_nodes, 3)),
        'mu_r_norm': torch.zeros((num_receptor_nodes, 5)), 
        'side_chain_vecs': torch.zeros((num_receptor_nodes, 2, 3)), 
        'batch': torch.zeros((num_receptor_nodes,), dtype=torch.long),
        'ptr': torch.tensor([0, num_receptor_nodes], dtype=torch.long),
    },
    'atom': {
        'x': torch.zeros((num_atom_nodes, num_features)),
        'pos': torch.zeros((num_atom_nodes, 3)),  
        'edge_mask': torch.ones((num_atom_nodes,)),
        'batch': torch.zeros((num_atom_nodes,), dtype=torch.long),
        'ptr': torch.tensor([0, num_atom_nodes], dtype=torch.long),
    },
    # ... other components ...
    'complex_t': {
        'tr': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes,)), 
        'rot': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes,)), 
        'tor': torch.zeros((num_ligand_nodes,)), 
    },
    'num_graphs': 1,  # Example value, adjust as needed
}

class CustomData:
    def __init__(self, data_dict):
        self.__dict__.update(data_dict)
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"'CustomData' object has no attribute '{name}'")

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[key]
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"'CustomData' object has no key '{key}'")

# Create a CustomData instance from the dummy_data dictionary
data = CustomData(dummy_data)

torch.onnx.export(model, (data, data), 'network.onnx', verbose=True)
```

I have done lots of assumption and there is a chance that I could have done a thing very wrong. It's my first exposure to exporting as `.onnx`. I wanted to basically somehow exported it as `.onnx` which is mainly getting blocked by inconsistency between the type of data i.e., `CustomData` versus the expected tuples, lists,etc.